# psql timing from bash

Tags: bash, postgresql

I need to remotely compare performance from many postgresql slaves

I can't find a good way to write something like:

```
echo "\timing on     select now() ; " | ssh me@server "psql foo_db"
```

tried with some '-e' for echo ,  some '\' ,

I just get 'timing is on' and some  extra arguments 'xxxx' ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system, `ssh` doesn't pass through the standard input at all, so I put the whole pipeline into the argument. What I ended up with was this:

```
ssh me@server "echo \"\timing on \\\\\ select now();\" | psql foo_db"
```

The `\"` inside the string allow me to use `'strings'` in the SQL itself if necessary. The awkward `\\\\\` sequence boils down as follows:

- the outer double-quoted string (passed to `ssh`) reduces each `\\` to `\`, giving `\\\`, for `echo "timing on \\\ select now();"`
- the inner double-quoted string (passed to the remote `echo`) reduces again, to `\\`, giving `timing on \\ select now();`
- This allows us to mix `psql` metacommands and SQL without multiple lines, as described in the manual:

> The special sequence \\ (two backslashes) marks the end of arguments and continues parsing SQL commands, if any. That way SQL and psql commands can be freely mixed on a line.

Answer (score 1):

a collegue tells me:

```
ssh me@server psql foo_db -Atq <<EOT
\timing on
select now();
EOT
```